# a lot of button add same addTarget(_:action:for:) method

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I'm working on a calculate app.
and has ton of button which I store in a big stackView (created in SB and no outlet).
each button cast some shadow (also set in SB attribute).
I want to get rid of shadow when button was pressed.
either tapGestureRecognizer or target action could only effect one UIButton.
any convenience way to acheive

PS I mean when button .touchupinside or tapGestureRecognizer .end .start when finger move button should still cast the shadow

help appreciated

Comment: You use SB but you are not using outlets, is it that a requirement? Do you want to remove the shadow of all buttons, when one tapped?

Comment: You could simply add the same target for many buttons... what's the issue?

Comment: @crom87  is ok to set outlet just I could't give each button an outlet~ just remove the one touched

Comment: Why wouldn't try to implement one general function inside class where you declare your @IBActions and call that function inside @IBActions? *shadowOffset* can help solve your task!

Comment: @AhmadF just is get ride of the shadow when .touchupinside when finger move it should regain the shadow

Comment: @mcsh0k is just in state .touchupinside when finger move should regain the shadow

Answer (score 3):

UIButton will highlighted on click, so check button setting Change the title color in highlight state config to same as default state Or you can set:

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

If you want to control Highlighted by code, you can disable normal highlighted by subclass Button and disable in touchesBegin:

```
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (self.state == UIControlStateHighlighted) {
        [self setHighlighted:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you notice that none of the used tags is "Objective-C", I think your answer should be written in Swift :)

Comment: In swift use as:  button.selected = false

Comment: thanks a lot.. great answer .. still have some issues.. I'm setting button attribute in storyboard not titleColor but button layer shadow.. is there a way subClass UIButton to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the same IBAction to multiple buttons, so that the same method is called for all of them

```
func buttonDidTouch(sender:UIButton) {}
```

If now you want to identify which exactly button is being called, you can use the UIButton.tag property to identify it. The tag can be set in the SB for each button.

Comment: tks..   edit the question guess not saying it clear I mean when button .touchupinside or tap .start .ended when finger move button should still cast the shadow

Answer (score 0):

There are so many way to achieve the goal but I'm going with below.

Just give my logic.
Take one temporary optional variable of `UIButton`

Ex.

```
var myTemButton: UIButton()?
```

In the button action method

```
@IBAction func myButtonActionFunc(_ sender: UIButton) {
  if myTemButton == nil {
    myTemButton = sender 
  }
  else {
    // Use "myTemButton" and write here code for remove shadow Or other stuff that you want.
  }

  // use "sender" and write code here for apply shadow of button or other stuff that you want.
}
```

Comment: tks..   edit the question guess not saying it clear I mean when button .touchupinside or tap start get rid the shadow when tap ended then regain the shadow...